# Md-tabs AngularJS working once only

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs, angular-material

I am new at using angularjs and I've been encountering some issues on md-tabs. The next button is working but when I click again on the first tab the next button is not working anymore. Can you please take a look on my codes and tell me what's wrong. Thanks!

**VIEW**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" ng-class="{ 'blur' : vm.preloader.action }">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedIndex">
        <md-tab label="Campaign Details">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <div class="md-content">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        Content 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="border-radius: 0; padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; width: 100%;" ng-click="nextTab()">NEXT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Recipients">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <div class="md-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        Content 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="nextTab()" style="width: 100%;">NEXT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Confirm">
            <md-content class="md-padding" ng-show="show_send_to_all">
                <div class="md-content">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                        Content 3
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="" style="width: 100%;">SEND</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    (function(){
   'use strict';

   angular
      .module('app')
      .controller('SmsManagementController', SmsManagementController);

   SmsManagementController.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'PreloaderService', 'ToastService', '$mdDialog', 'CaptchaService', '$localStorage', 'StaffRole', 'API'];
   function SmsManagementController($rootScope, PreloaderService, ToastService, $mdDialog, CaptchaService, $localStorage, StaffRole, API) {
      var vm = this;

      // Variables  
      vm.totalrecord = { general: 0 };
      vm.publicKey = API.captchakey;
      vm.displayCaptcha = !($.inArray($localStorage.currentUser.role, StaffRole) > -1);
      vm.preloader = {
         general: true
      }; 



      // Initialization
      Initialize();


      // Public functions
      function Initialize(){   
         PreloaderService.Display();
         PreloaderService.Hide(); 
      } 

      //Tabs
      $rootScope.max = 2;
      $rootScope.selectedIndex = 0;
      $rootScope.nextTab = function() {
         var index = ($rootScope.selectedIndex == $rootScope.max) ? 0 : $rootScope.selectedIndex + 1;
         $rootScope.selectedIndex = index;

      };

    } 

})();
```

Or maybe you can suggest a code on how will I convert this on jquery or javascript in order for me to have a next buttons for the tabs. I'm using a material design tabs of angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out.

Instead of using `$rootscope`, I changed it to `vm`. So, here's my new code for the tabs:

```
//Tabs
  vm.max = 2;
  vm.selectedIndex = 0;
  $rootScope.nextTab = function() {
     var index = (vm.selectedIndex == $rootScope.max) ? 0 : vm.selectedIndex + 1;
     vm.selectedIndex = index;

  };
```

And based on @Rakeschand solution, I passed `vm.selectedIndex` like this:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="vm.selectedIndex">
```

Thanks @Rakeschand for the idea :)

Comment: You should accept my answer instead of posting new answer, edit my answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Your NEXT button is not working because in your `next()` method you are doing iterations on `$rootscope`, do those iterations on `$scope`..

```
$scope.max = 2;
$scope.selectedIndex = 0;
$scope.nextTab = function() {
  var index = ($scope.selectedIndex == $scope.max) ? 0 : $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
  $scope.selectedIndex = index;
};
```

You are using `controllerAs` syntax so prefer using `vm`instead of `$scope` and also pass `vm.selectedIndex` here

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="vm.selectedIndex">
```

Comment: hi @rakeschand , i tried your solution but it's not working. The next button is not working entirely.

Comment: reproduce this error in jsfiddle I'll solve, otherwise this is how tabs work, you can check at material design website https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs